# Time-dependent coefficients in a Cox model with categorical variants

Tags: categorical-data, cox-model, time-varying-covariate

Suppose I have a data set contain three variants, looks like:

```
> head(dta)
   Sex   tumorsize   Histology       time     status
1    0         1.5           2    12.1000          0
2    1         1.8           1    38.4000          0
3    0         2.0           2    69.7333          0
4    1         6.0           3    18.0000          1
5    0         2.5           2    13.4000          1
6    0         1.5           2    44.5000          0
```

Sex: 1 for male; 0 for female., two levels

Histology: 1 for SqCC; 2 for High risk AC; 3 for low risk AC, three levels

Now I need to get a Time-dependent coefficients cox fit:

```
>library(survival)
>for(i in c(1,3) dta[,i] <- factor(dta[,i])
>fit <-
  coxph(
    Surv(time, status) ~  Sex + tumorsize +  Histology + tt(Histology),
    data = dta,
    tt = function(x, t, ...) x * log(t)
  )
```

But I keep gettting this error says:

```
    Error in if (any(infs)) warning(paste("Loglik converged before variable ",  :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
    In addition: Warning message:
    In Ops.factor(x, log(t)) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors.
```

How can I fix it? I know that the "Sex" and "Histology" are both
categorical variants. I  want to have a model that have two β(t) = a +
blog(t) for each histology level.
Thank you！

Answer (score 2):

I have never personally used the time-transform in `coxph`. According to [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Greg/vignettes/timeSplitter.html), factors need to be transformed into a design matrix in order to be able to multiply it with time:

```
dtafit <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~  Sex + tumorsize +  Histology + tt(Histology),
    data = dta, tt = function(x, t, ...) {
        mtrx <- model.matrix(~x)[,-1]
        mtrx * log(t)
        })
```

Comment: Many thanks! It solved the errors. But I have a new problem after running this code. I use `cox.zph(dtafit)` to test the proportional hazards assumption.  It still returns a p-value < .05. When I use tt() subfunction w/o any parament.`dtafit <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~  Sex + tumorsize +  Histology + tt(Histology),data = dta` The result of cox.zph(dtafit) suggest that the PH assumption is not significantly violated. Besides, might you give some adivice to deal with the Time-dependent coefficients in Cox model? I need to do the calibration and external validation after fitting. Thanks@Yuval